# how can I implement PList manipulation

Tags: ios, xamarin

I read here https://medium.com/@marksiu/what-is-plistbuddy-76cb4f0c262d

that plistbuddy is in usr/libexec/PlistBuddy.
But it is not there or at least I can't find it. Do you have to install something to get this ? I have xcode 12.5.1 installed on my Mac.

Comment: do you have XCode command line tools installed?

Comment: Yes I even have the latest version. But no plistbuddy

Comment: this might be better suited for https://apple.stackexchange.com